# Why isn't @Given repeatable?

Tags: java, annotations, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I am all new to Cucumber(jvm) and it all seems fine and dandy but :

I don't really know how to have multiple initial conditions (from various scenarios) written in various ways (elegantly) be implemented by a single method.

eg :

```
Scenario: I really am bad
    Given I really am inexperienced with Cucumber
    When I try to work
    Then what I produce is of poor quality

Scenario: I am on the way to become good (hopefully)
    Given I am a noob
    When I learn new things
    And I practice
    Then my level improves
```

Since `Given I really am inexperienced with Cucumber` and `Given I am a cuke noob` (although not semantically **identical**) are close enough for me to be implemented in the exact same way, I would like to be able to *link* them to the same method but

```java
@Given("^I really am inexperienced with Cucumber$")
@Given("^I am a cuke noob$")
public void checkMyLevelIsGenerallyLow() throws Throwable {
    // some very clever code to assess then confirm my mediocre level ... something like if(true) ...
}
```

But the code presented here-above won't compile as the `cucumber.api.java.en.@Given` annotation is not `java.lang.annotation.@Repeatable` ...

one simple solution would be to do something like

```java
public void checkMyLevelIsGenerallyLow() throws Throwable {
    // some very clever code to assess then confirm my mediocre level ... something like if(true) ...
}

@Given("^I really am inexperienced with Cucumber$")
public void check_I_really_am_inexperienced_with_Cucumber() throws Throwable {
    checkMyLevelIsGenerallyLow();
}

@Given("^I am a cuke noob$")
public void check_I_am_a_cuke_noob() throws Throwable {
    checkMyLevelIsGenerallyLow();
}
```

which would work just fine but would require lots of code for simple things and  I am pretty sure there are other ways.

Or even, as I asked myself writing down this question, "Am I simply approaching this question from the right side ?", is what I am trying to acheive even a good idea in terms of BDD ?

I think it's not all bad since gherkin is supposed to hold the semantic and sentence construction and vocabulary choices are contexte (hence scenario) dependent. Yet I should be free of implementing it in whatever way I like.

### So to wrap it all up :

- Should `@Given` be `@Repeatable` ?

  - If so, why isn't it ? Is there another way around ?
  - If not, what am I missing in terms of approach ?

Comment: Apart from any cucumber specific reasons, repeatable annotations are new with Java 8. So making `@Given` repeatable would limit the library to be used with Java 8 (or newer).

Comment: DAMN you are so fast :D i even barely pressed submit on a quite long and not really easy to read post and you've got a very helpfull insight !
You are absolutely right about @repeatable. But as for some workaround do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Regarding multi-expressive @given

It might not be the nicest way to do it but scratching my head I thought of that :

```java
@Given("^I really am inexperienced with Cucumber$|^I am a cuke noob$")
public void checkMyLevelIsGenerallyLow() throws Throwable {
    // some very clever code to assess then confirm my mediocre level ... something like if(true) ...
}
```

And it works !
It is exactly what I was looking for and can even be made a bit more readable like this :

```java
@Given("^I really am inexperienced with Cucumber$"+
      "|^I am a cuke noob$")
```

### Regarding the non-repeatability @given

as blalasaadri stated `@Given` may be `@Repeatable` but only from Java8 and further since `@Repeatable` was introduced in Java8.

### Special thanks

To Ceiling Gecko who made me remember that the simplest and most obvious solutions are usually the best and most elegant.

Comment: Nice one, given (heh) that I've never had to deal with Cucumber before, my answer was something I threw together blindly by going through the Cucumber docs (read: I have no clue what I'm doing), so it's great that you found an answer that fits. :) You can also accept your own answer (this is normal) so it gains more visibility for possible future readers.

Comment: Yes I am just reformatting it and adding bit's from your answer and @blalasaadri 's so it's comprehensive and as usefull as possible for future readers.
And BTW very nice educated guess there then ;)

Answer (score 4):

A long shot but wouldn't:

```
@Given("^I really am inexperienced with Cucumber$")
@And("^I am a cuke noob$")
public void checkMyLevelIsGenerallyLow() throws Throwable {
    // some very clever code to assess then confirm my mediocre level ... something like if(true) ...
}
```

work as expected?

Comment: aaaaand it works ! And as wanted on top of that. Yet that's oddly unsatisfying. Semantically I'd expect it to be an `@Or` annotation since I'll execture this method if I am in one case OR the other and not in case A AND case B.

Comment: AH Damn !!! It works half as much as wanted. You can add ONE other condition but you can't add multiple conditions :'(

Comment: you inspired me on this :) I'v tried something that works, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for the annotation not being repeatable would be, that repeatable annotations are new with Java 8. Using them for a library is therefore still problematic as you'll be limiting the user base considerably. (Remember, especially big corporations are slow at adapting new technology.)

As an alternative you could use the same Java function and a similar Given description; such as

```
Given My cucumber level is low because I'm a cuke noob
```

and

```
Given My cucumber level is low because I'm inexperienced
```

which could both be caught by

```
@Given("My cucumber level is low because I'm (.*)")
public void checkMyLevelIsGenerallyLow(String reason) throws Throwable {
    // ...
}
```

This would also pass the reason to the function as its first argument. But I'm not sure you *should* use the same function here as the cases are different.

Comment: It defeats the purpose as it requires to work the sentence knowing it has to be treated in the same way as the other.